# C++1z - Throwing compile error if condition occurs during template unfolding

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'm writing a template that defines a type that is given to it in type parameter pack, and whose position is the same as number passed to the template. Here's what I've written:

```
template<size_t I, typename T, typename... Ts> 
struct get_type {
    typedef typename std::conditional<I == 0, T, typename get_type<I-1, Ts...>::type>::type type;
};

template<size_t I, typename T>
struct get_type<I, T> {
    // This works only if compiler stops unfolding the template when I == 0
    static_assert(I == 0, "get_type - index out of bounds");
    typedef T type;
};
```

Problem with this approach, if we write code like this:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<double, get_type<1,int,double,float>::type>::value, "I wanted double!");
```

Compiler still "unfolds" the template to the end (even though it should know the type till then, exactly when `I` is equal to `0`), and at the end `I` overflows and is no longer equal to 0, which means `static_assert` throws error, that index `I` is out of bounds.  But I still want to somehow throw an error during compile time, if `I` is TRULLY out of bounds. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Would solving the problem that led to the above "solution" be enough?

Comment: What do you mean? The problem is that I want to preserve the compile error if client misuses my template. But having static_assert like that just doesn't work so I'm looking for alternate solution.

Comment: What I think you need is a way to generate an error if they ask for a type after the end of your type list.  Which has nothing to do with unfokding templates.  As written, the above question makes the unfolding appear central: I suspect that is merely a "I tried to solve the problem with a particular technique that failed".

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has to unfold the template otherwise it wouldn't know what the type of `type` is.

`std::tuple_element_t` already gives a (rather verbose) error if the index is out of bounds.

```
template<size_t I, typename... Ts>
using get_type_t = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
```

A more intuitive error message can be made by using this in concert with an explicit bounds check:

```
template<size_t I, typename... Ts>
struct get_type {
    using L=std::tuple<Ts...>;
    static_assert(I < 0 || I >= std::tuple_size<L>(), "out of bounds");
    using type = std::tuple_element_t<I, L>;
};

template<size_t I, typename... Ts>
using get_type_t = typename get_type<I, Ts...>::type;
```

Here's an example without the overhead of `std::tuple` (adapted from boostcon):

```
struct empty{};

template<class T>
struct tag_t:empty{};

template<class T>
tag_t<T> tag{};

template <typename ignore>
struct lookup;

template <std::size_t... ignore>
struct lookup<std::index_sequence<ignore...>> {
    template <typename nth>
    static nth
    apply(decltype(ignore, empty())..., tag_t<nth>, ...);
};

template<std::size_t I, class... Ts>
using get_type = decltype(
    lookup<std::make_index_sequence<I>>::apply(tag<Ts>...)
);

// Test
static_assert(std::is_same<get_type<1, int, float, int>, float>(), "");
static_assert(std::is_same<get_type<0, int, float, int>, int>(), "");
```

Comment: A `size_t` can never be `< 0`.  Make it a `ptr_diff_t`.  Second, using `tuple` has a cost, as `tuple` can be a large class.  Are there any restictions on types passed to `tuple`, or just on operations?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer I came up with:

```
struct error_type {}; 

template<size_t I, typename T, typename... Ts> 
struct get_type {
   typedef typename std::conditional<I == 0, T, typename get_type<I-1, Ts...>::type>::type type;
   static_assert(!std::is_same<type, error_type>::value, "get_type - index out of bounds");
};

template<size_t I, typename T>
struct get_type<I, T> {
    typedef typename std::conditional<I == 0, T, error_type>::type type;
};
```

But it seems a little verbose (we're creating a dummy structure), so I'm leaving this question in case someone comes up with something smarter then my solution...